# unable to import interface: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'interface'

Tags: python

I installed python-interface package via pip: `pip install python-interface` with the following output:

```
Requirement already satisfied: python-interface in c:\users\amar budhiraja\.conda\envs\keras\lib\site-packages (1.6.0)
Requirement already satisfied: six in c:\users\amar budhiraja\.conda\envs\keras\lib\site-packages (from python-interface) (1.12.0)
```

I then try to call it using the following import statement: `from interface import implements, Interface` but it results in the following import error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'interface'
```

Can someone point me to what I might be missing? I did restart my terminal after the installation of the package.

Comment: maybe you should use `python-interface` in the import ?

Comment: Make sure you're using correct env & python version

Comment: if you are using a virtual env, then you should install the packages with your virtual env commands.

Comment: Also ideally to implement interfaces in python, using `.pyi` specification is better option

Comment: My env is correct. I have installed packages previously in the same env and they all worked, except for this one. Any other hints on what could I be missing?

Comment: Inside this script that imports interface, right before, do `import sys; print(sys.path)`. This will print all search paths were python tries to find module. Look into those paths/dirs. Is there your installed module inside one of them? If not then Python won't find module. Probably your PIP used some other Python installation or environment and installed module there.